# Safari Mobile full screen for multiple pages

Tags: iphone, mobile, fullscreen, iphone-standalone-web-app

I was just reading this question [How do they do this - Mobile Site Added to Homescreen Appears as Standalone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195741/how-do-they-do-this-mobile-site-added-to-homescreen-appears-as-standalone-app)

I was wondering if there is a way to get it to stay in full screen mode for multiple pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found framework which will kinda do what I want, but I would still love to have a native way of keeping the web app from opening safari.

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/